# Performance Issue while adding members in bulk to multiple Public Groups

Tags: trigger, public-group

Through trigger trying to add bulk partner users (approx. 50) in bulk Public groups(approx. 50) but it takes a lot of time. 
**Is it something that on insert of members in public group Salesforce takes time to process in the backend?**

On debugging, I found that trigger logic is not taking time but the processing time increases after adding insert logic for inserting members in the public groups.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

First of all, you're inserting 2,500 records, and that's likely to have some level of performance cost regardless of what exactly it is you're inserting.

But with group members specifically, there is the potential to cause some [visibility calculations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.draes.meta/draes/draes_group_membership.htm) to take place, which will cost additional time. The magnitude of that performance impact will be dependent upon your specific sharing setup and the record volume associated with any sharing rules present.

Consider using Asynchronous Apex, such as a Queueable, to perform these updates, in order to keep your synchronous triggers performant.

Comment: I think the visibility calculations are themselves asynchronous, but adding a member also implies adding all parent users and groups (via role hierarchy settings), so this can easily produce tens-of-thousands of implied record creations. Your advice is still true, however: modifying a group should be done asynchronously, and definitely not in a trigger.

Comment: We have a functionality where we have used a custom object which has a lookup relationship to partner user. From custom object list view, we are selecting all records. And then through quick action we are updating selected records by selecting public group (created web component). In the backend, through trigger we are adding members(user related to select custom object records) in public group. Once membership updated successfully we are displaying public groups and their respective ids in the long text custom fields (in comma separated) under custom object.

Comment: I even thought of asynchronous apex but that won't work for me because after bulk insert I have to display public group details in custom field. Also, if in case any error occur while adding members, user will not get any error or notification while performing this functionality on UI.